# 503 Service Unavailable (Long Running MySQL query)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker

I have a script that exports a lot of data from a MySQL database hosted in a Docker container. All other requests are working fine without a 503 error - **a long running MySQL query is the only request getting the 503 error**.

PHP already has max execution and input time set to infinite, I set the TimeOut in Apache to an hour (1800). My first inclination is Apache is simply not waiting long enough / not receiving a response so it goes to a 503 error. Prior to setting the timeout to 1800 seconds, I was getting a 504 error.

The error happens roughly at the 60 to 65 second mark.

Anyone know of a setting in Apache that can be changed or some other solution?

Comment: If you have a long query, it's best to think how to run it asynchronous, and then return to the user when it's done. In this case you don't need apache, just php-cli or other language/tool.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Agreed - that is looking like the solution and I assume the best practice